# Split integers in string - python

Tags: python

I've got a bunch of numbers in a string.  I want to split them into individual digits so I can do more with them later.

```
number = [6, 18, 6, 4, 12, 18, 0, 18]
```

I want to split these like so....
ex: 6, 1, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 0, 1, 8

I've tried split(), I've tried list(str(number)), I've tried converting these to strings and integers and I have tried searching stackoverflow.

In other searches I keep seeing a list comprehension example like this, which I don't understand and don't get the desired result after trying:
    [int(i) for i in str(number)]

help??

Answer (score 2):

First you have to consider every element of the list as a string, and then cast back every character to an integer.

```
def customSplit(l):
        result = []
        for element in l:
                for char in str(element):
                        result.append(int(char))
        return result

print(customSplit([6, 18, 6, 4, 12, 18, 0, 18]))
# prints [6, 1, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 0, 1, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[ digit for x in number for digit in str(x) ]
```

which produces a list of strings:

['6', '1', '8', '6', '4', '1', '2', '1', '8', '0', '1', '8']

or

```
[ int(digit) for x in number for digit in str(x) ]
```

if you'd prefer a list of single-digit integers:

```
[6, 1, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 0, 1, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain` like so:

```
>>> list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(map(str, numbers))))
[6, 1, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 0, 1, 8]
```

---

I posted this mainly so I could compare it to a [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org) equivalent:

```
>>> numbers |> map$(str) |> chain.from_iterable |> map$(int) |> list
```

while looks nicer. If you like Unicode characters, you can replace `|>` with `↦`:

```
>>> numbers ↦ map$(str) ↦ chain.from_iterable ↦ map$(int) ↦ list
```

In standard Python, a list comprehension is probably more readable.